# Why dynamodb type for `ReturnValue` contain string

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
export type ReturnValue = "NONE"|"ALL_OLD"|"UPDATED_OLD"|"ALL_NEW"|"UPDATED_NEW"|string;      
export type ReturnConsumedCapacity = "INDEXES"|"TOTAL"|"NONE"|string;
export type ReturnItemCollectionMetrics = "SIZE"|"NONE"|string;
export type ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure = "ALL_OLD"|"NONE"|string;
```

These type definitions are copied from aws-sdk. Why these type definitions contain string. How it is different from just writing

```
export type ReturnValue = string;
```

I don't get any auto-completion because it contains string type.

Comment: At least it tells *you* what the specific values are, could just be that the `string` is there to make the computer happy.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK v3 is built in a way that allows Amazon to make updates to APIs without breaking customers using an older SDK. By adding `| string` at the end, Amazon preserves the ability of a service to add additional enum items in the future for command outputs.

Similarly, the TypeScript generated for required properties appends an `| undefined` to the end of the type definition, while non-required properties are purely optional objects. This is done to allow Amazon to later remove required properties from the model without breaking customers. Amazon's API operations frequently drop required properties when the operation gets overloaded to handle additional configuration options.

These are Amazon's stated reasons, but they seem to apply more to output command types than input commands. Amazon does not consider that input and output models should have different levels of flexibility. It does make sense that a command output would preserve maximum flexibility for the service to make updates, but it makes less sense that command inputs must be equally flexible. They seem to only be considering one half of the robustness principle.

Comment: But you loose the very purpose of types : error checking and auto completion. If they want to serve the older sdks then they can bring a minor version update.

Comment: @AnkitAabad they also need to consider correctness of types. They believe adding enum values and removing required properties is a non-breaking change, and so the types they provide are correct given the constraints of typescript and their versioning rules. I'm not saying its a good user experience, just explaining the logic to answer the question.

Comment: Adding an extra value in the union will not break existing codebase. If someone wants to use a new feature then update the minor version. We don't need string in the union to remove any available options.

Comment: An existing operation may gain an additional enum value in a response. If you have a switch statement that you think is an exhaustive check, when the new enum value arrives in a response your code may panic (due to unexpected input). By specifying that they may send any string value, they are not mis-leading customers about the range of values available in a response. Remember this is for existing operations, and not new API features that customers need to opt-in to using.